# Rails and class variables: will this persist across users and server calls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

We're on Rails 3.0.6.

Will the following code persist across page loads and users in Rails? Or does it get redefined with every request? The code lives at the top of a controller.

```
@@list = []

hero = {}
hero['name'] = 'so'
hero['superpowers'] = ['coding', 'qa', 'spec_writing']
@@list.push hero

hero2 = {}
hero2['name'] = 'so2'
hero2['superpowers'] = ['coding']
@@list.push hero2
... more Hashes pushed into @@list
```

The list only changes once a month, and we would like to efficiently and quickly make this data available to page requests. We will eventually use Rails.cache to read from the database, but we're using the following approach for now (assuming it works).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In development, the default behavior is for the class to be reloaded on each request, thereby resetting your class variable. In production, however, the class is initialized once and so the class variable will persist across multiple requests and multiple sessions.

You should move to a proper caching technique as soon as you can.  You cannot, obviously, persist the value beyond the *reloading* of the class when the application is restarted.  Furthermore, if the web server is multi-threaded (as it is likely to be), it may be running multiple instances of the application on different threads which *do not* share the class variables, potentially creating inconsistencies between requests.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael! Agreed. Caching is high up in the queue.

Comment: Just to clarify, the hashes defined with "hero" and "hero2" will get persisted because @@list contains a reference to them? Is this right?

Comment: @Crashalot Yes, I believe they should persist.

Answer (score 1):

I've just came across the same issue and found this post. I know it's an old question, but posting my answer just in case someone else faces similar issue...

I think for cases where **database** or **Rails.cache** can not be used for some reason then the best place to put those values is Application class. Just define some attribute and initialize it. Then it's easy to access it just like **Rails.application.heros**. Quick and dirty sample below:

in config/application.rb

```
module YourRailsApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    attr_reader :heros

    initializer "init heros" do 
      @heros = []

      hero = {}
      hero['name'] = 'so'
      hero['superpowers'] = ['coding', 'qa', 'spec_writing']
      @heros.push hero

      hero2 = {}
      hero2['name'] = 'so2'
      hero2['superpowers'] = ['coding']

      @heros.push hero2
    end

    #Other application sutff...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes used what I called ***the cache of the poor***.

It worked as follow:

- in an initializer, add: `MY_CACHE_HASH = {}`
- wherever you want: `MY_CACHE_HASH[:foo] = :bar`
- wherever you need `MY_CACHE_HASH[:foo] #=> :bar`

I wouldn't recommend it though: what would you do if your server crashes?

Answer (score 0):

If you have data that *won't be changed while rails is running* then it's fine to use a `@@class_variable`.

keep in mind that (in the default development configuration) controller classes are re-loaded at every request, so if you need to say, read the data from a file, consider putting the code to initialize the data into config/application.rb in a `$global` or `CONSTANT_VAR`.

Answer (score 0):

So what you're describing is a datastructure that is not a database. I think it's perfectly reasonable to have items that "never" change in your code and not in your database.

for example, You could have:

In app/models/hero.rb

```
class Hero
  @@all_heros = []
  def self.all_heros
    @@all_heros
  end
  def self.add_hero(hero)
    @@all_heros << hero
  end
  def initialize(name, superpowers=[])
    @name = name
    @superpowers = superpowers
  end
end

# this will get executed on load
Hero.add_hero( Hero.new("so", ['coding', 'qa', 'spec_writing']))
```

Then later in your code, you'll access:

```
@heros = Hero.all_heros
```

And later you can swap out for a database backed store if you need on.